# How to subset a data frame using Pandas based on a group criteria?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data set with the following structure

```
User     X
1        0
1        0
2        0
2        0
2        1
3        0
3        0
```

I would like to take a subset of the data such that the sum of column X for each User is 0. Given the above example, the subset should only include the observations for users 1 and 3 as follows

```
User     X
1        0
1        0
3        0
3        0
```

Is there a way to do this using the groupby function without grouping the data? I want the subset to include the individual observations.

Comment: Do we know that all `X` are >= 0, or do you need to worry about `-1,+1`?

Comment: all the X values are >= 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868335/190597), which selects rows using a boolean mask, works well even if the DataFrame has a non-unique index. 
My method, which selects rows using index values, is slightly slower when the index is unique and *significantly slower* when the index contains duplicate values.

@roland: Please consider accepting DSM's answer instead.

---

You could use a [`groupby-filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
In [16]: df.loc[df.groupby('User')['X'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 0).index]
Out[16]: 
   User  X
0     1  0
1     1  0
5     3  0
6     3  0
```

---

By itself, the groupby-filter just returns this:

```
In [29]: df.groupby('User')['X'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 0)
Out[29]: 
0    0
1    0
5    0
6    0
Name: X, dtype: int64
```

but you can then use its index,

```
In [30]: df.groupby('User')['X'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 0).index
Out[30]: Int64Index([0, 1, 5, 6], dtype='int64')
```

to select the desired rows using `df.loc`.

---

Here is the benchmark I used:

```
In [49]: df2 = pd.concat([df]*10000)   # df2 has a non-unique index
```

I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>'d this one because it was taking too long to finish:

```
In [50]: %timeit df2.loc[df2.groupby('User')['X'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 0).index]
```

When I realized my mistake, I made a DataFrame with a unique index:

```
In [51]: df3 = df2.reset_index()     # this gives df3 a unique index

In [52]: %timeit df3.loc[df3.groupby('User')['X'].filter(lambda x: x.sum() == 0).index]
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit df3.loc[df3.groupby("User")["X"].transform(sum) == 0]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
```

This shows DSM's method performs well even with a non-unique index:

```
In [54]: %timeit df2.loc[df2.groupby("User")["X"].transform(sum) == 0]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.2 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative to @unutbu's answer, there's also

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby("User")["X"].transform(sum) == 0]
   User  X
0     1  0
1     1  0
5     3  0
6     3  0
```

This creates a `df`-length boolean Series to use as a selector:

```
>>> df.groupby("User")["X"].transform(sum) == 0
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
6     True
dtype: bool
```

`transform` is used when you want to "broadcast" the result of a groupby reduction operation back up to all the elements of each group.  It comes in handy.

Comment: can u do a pull request to add this to the cookbook? (maybe to the SQL section as well) - this is basically the having statement

Comment: This is a significantly better answer than mine since it works well even if the DataFrame has a non-unique index. My method can be quite slow in that case. Selecting with a full boolean mask is more robust than selecting by index values.