# keep dataframe rows meeting a condition into each group of the same dataframe grouped by

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe.

```
    c1  c2  v1  v2
0   a   a   1   2
1   a   a   2   3
2   b   a   3   1
3   b   a   4   5
5   c   d   5   0
```

I wish to have the following output.

```
    c1  c2  v1  v2
0   a   a   2   3
1   b   a   4   5
2   c   d   5   0
```

The rule. First group dataframe by c1, c2. Then into each group, keep the row with the maximun value in column v2.
Finally, output the original dataframe with all the rows not satisfying the previous rule dropped.

What is the better way to obtain this result? Thanks.

Going around, I have found also [this solution based on apply method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488080/python-pandas-filter-rows-after-groupby)

Comment: do you mind sharing the code you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`groupby-transform` to generate a boolean selection mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27868335/190597):

```
grouped = df.groupby(['c1', 'c2'])
mask = grouped['v2'].transform(lambda x: x == x.max()).astype(bool)
df.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)
```

yields

```
  c1 c2  v1  v2
0  a  a   2   3
1  b  a   4   5
2  c  d   5   0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that you get one single row per group, you can sort the values by "v2" before grouping and then just take the last row (the one with the highest v2-value).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"c1": ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"], "c2": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "d"], "v1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "v2": [2, 3, 1, 5, 0]})

df.sort_values("v2").groupby(["c1", "c2"]).last().reset_index()

result:

    c1  c2  v1  v2
0   a   a   2   3
1   b   a   4   5
2   c   d   5   0
```

Comment: +1, but yes, If there are multiple rows with the same max `v2` value in a group, then only one of them will be selected using this method, and you won't know which one.