# pandas - filter on groups which have at least one column containing non-null values in a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have the following python pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Id': ['1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3'], 'A': ['TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE'], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan, 'abc', np.nan, np.nan, 'def'],'C': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, '456']})

>>> print(df)
  Id      A    B    C
0  1   TRUE  NaN  NaN
1  1   TRUE  NaN  NaN
2  1   TRUE  abc  NaN
3  2   TRUE  NaN  NaN
4  2   TRUE  NaN  NaN
5  3  FALSE  def  456
```

I want to end up with the following dataframe:

```
>>> print(dfout)
  Id     A    B   C
0  1  TRUE  abc NaN
```

The same Id value can appear on multiple rows.  Each Id will either have the value TRUE or FALSE in column A consistently on all its rows.  Columns B and C can have any value, including NaN.
I want one row in dfout for each Id that has A=TRUE and show the max value seen in columns B and C.  But if the only values seen in columns B and C = NaN for all of an Id's rows, then that Id is to be excluded from dfout.

- Id 1 has `A=TRUE`, and has `B=abc` in its third row, so it meets
  the requirements.
- Id 2 has `A=TRUE`, but columns B and C are `NaN` for
  both its rows, so it does not.
- Id 3 has `A=FALSE`, so it does not
  meet requirements.

I created a `groupby` df on Id, then applied a mask to only include rows with A=TRUE.  But having trouble understanding how to remove the rows with `NaN` for all rows in columns B and C.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Id'])
mask = grouped['A'].transform(lambda x: 'TRUE' == x.max()).astype(bool)
df.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True)

  Id     A    B    C
0  1  TRUE  NaN  NaN
1  1  TRUE  NaN  NaN
2  1  TRUE  abc  NaN
3  2  TRUE  NaN  NaN
4  2  TRUE  NaN  NaN
```

Then I tried several things along the lines of:

```
df.loc[mask].reset_index(drop=True).all(['B'],['C']).isnull
```

But getting errors, like:

> " TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' ".

Using  python 3.6, pandas 0.23.0; Looked here for help: [keep dataframe rows meeting a condition into each group of the same dataframe grouped by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27925447/keep-dataframe-rows-meeting-a-condition-into-each-group-of-the-same-dataframe-gr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution has three parts to it.

1. Filter dataframe to keep rows where column A is True
2. Groupby Id and use first which will return first not null value
3. Use dropna on the resulting dataframe on columns B and C with how = 'all'

   df.loc[df['A'] == True].groupby('Id', as_index = False).first().dropna(subset = ['B', 'C'], how = 'all')

   ```
       Id  A       B   C
   0   1   True    abc NaN
   ```

Comment: perfect - very clean; i modified the bit to df['A'] == 'TRUE' for my example